# Error in mod_lhcping after upgrading to 19.09.1

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am getting the following error after upgrading from ejabberd 18.04 to 19.09.1
Not that proficient with erlang, please help me in debugging this issue.

Logs:

```
12:26:43.791 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.506.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: call to undefined function gen_mod:get_opt(send_pings, #{ahenviroment => false,ahprotocol => "https://",basedomain => "sit3lhc.1atesting.in",iqdisc => no_queue,...}, #Fun<mod_lhcping.0.4469384>, false)
12:26:43.791 [critical] Failed to start module mod_lhcping: 
{error,{{undef,[{gen_mod,get_opt,
                         [send_pings,
                          #{ahenviroment => false,ahprotocol => "https://",
                            basedomain => "localhost",
                            iqdisc => no_queue,
                            ping_address =>
                                "https://localhost/xmppservice/operatorstatus",
                            ping_interval => 5,send_pings => true,
                            timeout_action => kill},
                          #Fun<mod_lhcping.0.4469384>,false],
                         []},
                {mod_lhcping,init,1,[{file,"src/mod_lhcping.erl"},{line,120}]},
                {gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},
                {gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},
                {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                          [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]},
        {child,undefined,'mod_lhcping_localhost',
               {mod_lhcping,start_link,
                            [<<"localhost">>,
                             #{ahenviroment => false,ahprotocol => "https://",
                               basedomain => "localhost",
                               iqdisc => no_queue,
                               ping_address =>
                                   "https://localhost/xmppservice/operatorstatus",
                               ping_interval => 5,send_pings => true,
                               timeout_action => kill}]},
               transient,2000,worker,
               [mod_lhcping]}}}
12:26:43.792 [critical] ejabberd initialization was aborted because a module start failed.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The module is not updated to recent ejabberd changes that change how the modules options are defined in the source code. And quite probably there are other parts of the module that are not up to date with ejabberd current API...